# Javascript convert arrow notation to Function for use with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I am trying to work with a Google Geocoding API Example and need the code to work with Internet Explorer.  As their example includes an arrow function "=>"  I was wondering if someone could help me re-express the code in a manner which Internet Explorer will play with.

Thanks in advance.

Code example is from:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse#maps_geocoding_reverse-html

And is listed as follows:

```
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: { lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997 },
  });
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  const input = document.getElementById("latlng").value;
  const latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
  const latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]),
    lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]),
  };
  geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Use babel to transpile the code.

Comment: Cool that found the solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very popular and useful tool called [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert any ES6+ to ES5, or even ES3, which Internet Explorer understands.